# How do I define already-defined authors when converting from SVN to Git?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I'm attempting to convert an SVN repository to Git, mostly trying to piece together the process from these two blogs:

[John Albin Wilkins](https://john.albin.net/git/convert-subversion-to-git)

[Eelke Blok](https://blokspeed.net/blog/2010/09/converting-from-subversion-to-git)

and this StackOverflow post:

[cmcginty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3972103/6673905)

I created a file to map SVN users to Git users (Wilkins calls it `authors-transform.txt`, while Blok and 'cmcginty' call it `users.txt`), even though I don't understand its purpose or how it's supposed to look.  I used Wilkins's script,

```
svn log -q | awk -F '|' '/^r/ {sub("^ ", "", $2); sub(" $", "", $2); print $2" = "$2" "}' | sort -u > authors-transform.txt
```

To the best of my understanding, I've successfully completed the procedure up to the point of running `$ git svn fetch`.  When I attempt that, the process ends with the error

```
$ git svn fetch
...
Author: jimi@JH.EXPERIENCE.ORG not defined in authors-transform.txt file
```

It isn't clear from the output that this is a breaking error in the process, but Blok identifies it as such.  At this point, I'm supposed to "fix" the `authors-transform.txt` file, but I have no clue how.  This author is in the file:

```
jimi@JH.EXPERIENCE.ORG = jimi@JH.EXPERIENCE.ORG
```

There are no further lines I can add to `authors-transform.txt` that will cause this user to be more included in the file that he already is.

The only additional StackOverflow questions I can find that's relevant to this topic are [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037166/author-not-defined-when-importing-svn-repository-into-git) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36506457/git-svn-clone-author-not-defined-in-users-txt).  They mention spaces at the end of names, which I've fixed in `authors-transform.txt`, and the file encoding of `authors-transform.txt`.  It's hard to imagine that encoding is an issue, since I'm not on Windows or using any other software that would interfere with encoding (I'm using Ubuntu 20.04), but in any case there are no actionable suggestions regarding encoding on those pages.

What am I supposed to do to make this process proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evidently, `git svn` requires that the lines of the authors file adhere to a specific format, which wasn't clear from the documentation I'd been reading.  [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3972103/6673905) explains it well.  The format is

```
user1 = First Last Name <email@address.com>
user2 = First Last Name <email@address.com>
...
```

where the names on the left hand side are SVN users, and the right hand side is the name and Git-registered email of the Git users.  Note that the email address must be enclosed in angled brackets `<>`.

My confusion was compounded by the fact that I was following Wilkins's blog post most closely, and either my browser or his web publishing technology was treating the angled brackets `<>` as markup so that they and their contents were not rendered on my page, leaving

```
user1 = First Last Name
user2 = First Last Name
...
```

Thus, none of the authors in my authors file were properly defined, and `git svn` stopped and complained about only the first SVN user it encountered, which was `jimi@JH.EXPERIENCE.ORG`.

After correcting each line of the authors file to use the correct format (with emails in angled brackets), the `$ git svn fetch` command worked as advertised.

Answer (score 0):

Try [specifying path](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#Documentation/git-svn.txt---authors-fileltfilenamegt) to the authors file in the commandline options:

```sh
git svn fetch --authors-file='/path/to/authors-transform.txt'
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that didn't change the error.